# Magit deprecates `magit-popup`. Which of my packages depend on it?

Tags: magit, debugging

How do I get Emacs to report which packages in my running Emacs depend on `magit-popup`?

Soon Magit will stop supporting `magit-popup` because it has transitioned to the replacement `transient`. Somehow Magit (in preparation for version 3.0.0) is detecting a dependency on `magit-popup` and [warns about this repeatedly](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/master/lisp/magit-obsolete.el), to the point of making Magit unusable.

As described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3877) the message is written considerately and is well intentioned, but does not give any guidance on how to figure out which package has the dependency on `magit-popup`.

That GitHub issue resolves when the reporter finds a dependency in their local Emacs configuration. I've searched my local config, and I don't find any dependencies on `magit-popup` so I seem to be stuck.

Maybe I need to get Emacs itself to tell me at run-time what's causing this apparent dependency?

Assuming I know nothing about debugging Emacs Lisp, **how do I track down exactly what is causing this `magit-popup` dependency** to the precision where I know exactly what to remove and/or file bug reports against?

Comment: You've followed the advice to use `M-x rgrep` and turned up no instances of the text `magit-popup` at all?

Comment: There are instances, but they're in things like themes listing the modes they will colourise. I don't want to rely on a brute `grep`, instead I'm asking: How do I get Emacs to tell me precisely where the *dependency* is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function which produces that warning is `magit--magit-popup-warning`.

You can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `debug-on-entry` <kbd>RET</kbd> `magit--magit-popup-warning` <kbd>RET</kbd> to discover what is causing it to be called.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Debugger Commands` for what you can do from inside the debugger, and how to exit it.

Use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `cancel-debug-on-entry` if you don't want that to happen any more.

---

Using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep` to search in your Emacs config for the following regexp will *probably* produce all of the relevant results, as well:

`magit-\(define\|change\|remove\)-popup`

You can see the complete list of targeted functions at the end of the `magit-obsolete.el` library, via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library`.

Comment: Beautiful! `debug-on-entry` leads me straight to the culprit, `magithub`. Now I can follow the warning's advice and report a bug.